# Loading Vector data into OpenLayers3 from Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geojson, openlayers

I'm using Geoserver to serve my spatial data which is being displayed using OpenLayers 3.

I've so far been able to load my data as TilesWMS from my geoserver, but in order to select the data I need to be able to load it in as a Vector.

I'm using this code as my import

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/LiDAR/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=LiDAR:lidar_projects_completed&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json'
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 2.0)',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(vector);
```

Loading the URL into a web browser returns the multipart feature, so it leads me to think I need to handle it differently then just 'adding the layer'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because of the same origin policy. Use a relative url (ProxyPass) or JSONP instead. Also check out the vector-wfs example in OpenLayers 3 (but this uses a BBOX strategy).

Also note that ol.source.GeoJSON will be removed with version 3.5.0 and you should use ol.source.Vector with a format instead.

Comment: Thanks bartvde, thats helped some.  I've now been able to import the JSON data into a local variable.
I'm not trying to import it into the layer using this exmaple code:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html

Comment: var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(JSON)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'yellow',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)'
    })
  })
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);